# Input validation in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, validation

I am developing the CRM and facing some troubles in model validation.The process looks simple  when only one object in the model(i am using EF) is validated on the form. But when i am trying to process validation on multiply objects, only one top record got validated. Here is the code:

```
@model List<CROS1.Models.GetParams_Result> // 

<h3 align="center">
    Please fill report params
</h3>


<div class="sidebar_item">
    @using (@Ajax.BeginForm("ConfirmGeneration", "Home", ajaxOptions: new AjaxOptions
                                                                           {
                                                                               HttpMethod = "GET",
                                                                               UpdateTargetId = "params",
                                                                               InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                                                               LoadingElementId = "resultLoadingDiv",

                                                                           }, htmlAttributes: new { id = "Form2" }))
    {
        <table id="hor-minimalist-b">
            <tread>
                <tr>
                    <th scope ="col">Report</th>
                    <th scope ="col">Filter</th>
                    <th scope ="col">Value</th>
                </tr> 
            </tread>
            @foreach (CROS1.Models.GetParams_Result res in Model)
            {

                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayTextFor(r => res.R_name)
                        </td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayTextFor(r => res.Filter_name)
                        </td>
                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(r => res.Value)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(r=>res.Value)

                         </td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(r => res.Unity)
                        </td>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(r=>res.F_id)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(r=>res.R_id)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(r=>res.Filter_id,new{id="some"})
                        @Html.HiddenFor(r => res.F_name)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(r => res.Filter_name)*@
                        @Html.HiddenFor(r=>res.DefaultValue)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(r=>res.Visibles)
                    </tr>

                </tbody>


            }
        </table>


      @*  <input type="submit" id="submGetParams" />*@

    }
</div>
```

What i should do in this case? How the model must look like to be able to perform such validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate through each item in your list of items returned, appending the iteration number to each items element, this should help: [mvc clientside validation for nested (collection) properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511386/mvc-clientside-validation-for-nested-collection-properties)